# Sum of distances

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections

We consider the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=1$$ where $p>q>0$. The eccentricity of the ellipse is $\epsilon =\sqrt{1-\frac{q^2}{p^2}}$, and the points $(\pm \epsilon p, 0)$ of the axis $x$ are called focal points and are symbolized with $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Verify that $\gamma (t)=(p \cos t, q \sin t)$ is a parametrization of the ellipse.

Prove that the sum of the distance of a point $K$ of the ellipse from $F_1$ and $F_2$ doesn't depend on $K$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

For $x=p \cos t$ and $y=q \sin t $  we have $$\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=\frac{p^2\cos^2 t}{p^2}+\frac{q^2 \sin^2 t}{q^2}=\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1$$

So $\gamma (t)$ is a parametrization of the ellipse.

Let $K=(x, y)$. Let $D_1$ be the distance of $K$ from $F_1=(\epsilon p, 0)$ and $D_2$ the distance of $K$ from $F_2=(-\epsilon p, 0)$.

Then $D_1^2=(x-\epsilon p)^2+y^2$ and $D_2^2=(x+\epsilon p)^2+y^2$.

For $x=p\cos t , y=q\sin t$ we have $$D_1^2=(p\cos t-\epsilon p)^2+q^2\sin^2 t = \dots =p^2(1-\cos t \epsilon )^2 \Rightarrow D_1=p(1-\cos t\epsilon) \\ D_2^2=(p\cos t+\epsilon p)^2+q^2\sin^2 t = \dots =p^2(1+\cos t \epsilon )^2 \Rightarrow D_2=p(1+\cos t\epsilon)$$ So $$D_1+D_2=2p$$ Is this correct? Could I improve something at the fomulation?

$$$$

**EDIT1:**

After that I am asked to prove that the product of the distances of the tangent line at a point $L$ of the ellipse from $F_1$ and $F_2$ doesn't depend on $L$.

I have found the tangent vector $\gamma '(t)=(-p \sin t, q \cos t)$.

What do I have to do next? I got stuck right now...

$$$$$

**EDIT2:**

If $p$ is any point on the ellipse, the line joining $f_1$ and $p$ and that joining $f_2$ and $p$ make equal angles with the tangent line to the ellipse at $p$.

Could you give me some hints what we are supposed to do in this case?

Comment: This looks reasonable to me. Probably one can't improve this approach much without, e.g., changing the parameterization or doing something more drastic.

Comment: Ok... After that I am asked to prove that the product of the distances of the tangent line at a point $L$ of the ellipse from $F_1$ and $F_2$ doesn't depend on $L$. I have found the tangent vector $\gamma '(t)=(-p \sin t, q \cos t)$. What do I have to do next? I got stuck right now... @Travis

Comment: Do you know how to find the distance between a line (say, in parametric form) and a fixed point?

Comment: Do we have to write the equation of the tangent line in the parametric form? @Travis

Comment: Yes, though one can extract a useful general formula from this in terms of the constants defining the line and point.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... Thank you very much!! :-) @Travis I edited the question above... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: You mean the question in Edit 2? I might just write it up as a new question altogether (linking to this one). It's generally good practice to ask separate questions separately, and anyway the question will probably get more attention that way anyway. As for the new question in the edit, probably proceeding naively (computing the tangent line at an arbitrary point on the ellipse and computing the line segments to the foci and computing the relevant angles) isn't too inefficient, though when working with conic sections often one can write a very efficient answer with some slick observation.

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!! :-) @Travis

Comment: You're welcome! (If you do ask the question separately, perhaps edit your question here to include a link to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are not very useful when you want to calculate how far a point is from a line, because vectors are not localised. So I use cartesian coordinates instead.

The distance of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ from a line $ax+by+c=0$ is given by the formula $$\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

For your question, you can take the equation of the tangent as $qx\cos\theta+py\sin\theta=pq$ , and the problem is then pretty straightforward.

**EDIT:** This is to answer your edit.

Say the foot of perpendiculars dropped from the foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ on the tangent at $P$ are $S_1$ and $S_2$. Using the distance formula above you can easily find the ratio $\dfrac{F_1S_1}{F_2S_2}$. Using the definition of ellipse it is very easy to find the ratio $\dfrac{PF_1}{PF_2}$ . Show that these ratios are equal and hence you'll prove that $\triangle PS_1F_1 \sim \triangle PS_2F_2$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) I edited the question above... Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @MaryStar check out the edit

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!! :-)